# Built ready to use Node js 0.4.x

Tags: node.js, dojo

Does anyone know where to find a working\built version of node.js v 0.4.x?
It´s to compile dojo 1.7.3 claro theme.

Comment: Can you clone it, checkout that tag and then build it yourself?

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify what platform you need, but based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16430919/201952), I'm guessing Windows.

There was no node for Windows [until 0.6](http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/11/05/node-v0-6-0/).  Certain 0.4 releases built under Cygwin, but that generally sucked.  Given that, it's unlikely you'll find 0.4 binaries for Windows.

You can get [old binaries starting with 0.6 here](http://nodejs.org/dist/).

For other platforms, simply clone the repo and checkout the `v0.4.12` tag, then build.  [Step-by-step instructions here.](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation)

Answer (score 0):

you can also the node version manager [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to install any version of node.js back to `0.1.14`.

Once you have nvm installed you can install `0.4.12` with the commands

```
nvm ls-remote
nvm install 0.4.12
nvm use 0.4.12
```